# Angular Dropdown navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I am trying to create a **complex breadcrumbs** with **dropdown-navigation** in such way:

[image]

I'm struggling with *outside click* issue: when I need to close dropdown on click somewhere out of the element, BUT if I click another navigation item - it should be open (there is only one opened breadcrumb in same time).

I did in such way:

1) I detect outsideClick by containing an event.target in parent element

2) Switching is happened by closing all breadcrumbs and opened one that is needed.

[simple example of breadcrumbs](https://plnkr.co/edit/asFkb1DIlVvIgVp6tfv3?p=preview) Plunker

timeplate:

```
     <ul #simpleBreadcrumbs>

      <li *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs"
        class="bread_item"
        (click)="toogleStateOfSubparagraphs(breadcrumb)">

        <div>
          <span>{{breadcrumb.label}}</span>
          <i class="icon-arrows-glyph-1_bold-down"
             *ngIf="!breadcrumb.isOpen">
          </i>
          <i class="icon-arrows-glyph-1_bold-up"
             *ngIf="breadcrumb.isOpen">
          </i>
        </div>


        <ul class="switcher__list dropdown__list"
            *ngIf="breadcrumb.isOpen">
          <li class="switcher__item dropdown__item" *ngFor="let subparagraph of breadcrumb.subparagraphs">
            <a class="switcher__item-href">
              {{subparagraph.label}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

  </ul>
```

component class:

```
export class App {
  breadcrumbs:any[];

  @ViewChild('simpleBreadcrumbs') private _breadcrumbsTemplate: ElementRef;
  _currentOpenedBreadcrumbs:any;

  constructor() {
    this.breadcrumbs = [
      {
        label: 'First',
        isOpen: false,
        subparagraphs: [
          {
            label: '1.1'
          },
          {
            label: '1.2'
          }]
      },
      {
        label: 'Second',
        isOpen: false,
        subparagraphs: [
          {
            label: '2.1'
          },
          {
            label: '2.2'
          }]
      }];
  }

  toogleStateOfSubparagraphs(breadcrumb) {
     if (this._currentOpenedBreadcrumbs === breadcrumb) {
      this._closeSubparagraphs();
      this._currentOpenedBreadcrumbs = null;
      return;
    }
    this.breadcrumbs
      .forEach((bread: IBreadCrumb) => {
        bread.isOpen = false;
        if (bread === breadcrumb) {
          bread.isOpen = true;
        }
      });
    this._currentOpenedBreadcrumbs = breadcrumb;
  }

  _closeSubparagraphs() {
    this.breadcrumbs
      .map((bread) => {
        bread.isOpen = false;
        return bread;
      });
  }

  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  public onEscapeClick(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event.which === 27 && !this._breadcrumbsTemplate.nativeElement.contains(event.target as Node)) {
      this._closeSubparagraphs();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onOutsideClick(event: Event): void {
   if (!this._breadcrumbsTemplate.nativeElement.contains(event.target as Node)) {
      this._closeSubparagraphs();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried ng4-breadcrumbs? 
https://github.com/Centroida/ng4-breadcrumbs

Comment: No, I think that this is a bad idea((
Because this package is still under development.
And the main, this is not what I need exactly. @Eedoh

Comment: @Hedgehog - but analysing their code - not necessarily using it may give you answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your CSS file to:

```
.bread_item {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 padding: 30px;
```

}

Is this what you were looking for?
If not, than i might have misinterpreted your question.

Your previous css made it so that the second element was also pushed down on clicking the first element.